Stuck at GNU GRUB terminal when trying to install Xubuntu 24.04
As the title suggests I'm stuck at a weird GNU GRUB terminal when I'm trying to install Xubuntu 24.04. Here is how I got from the iso to booting.
First I installed Xubuntu (desktop version) .iso file from the China server then used balenaEtcher to write it to my 32GB generic USB, then set priority to my USB, boot it up and it just show me a weird prompt like this so:

My computer specs are:
   Intel Pentium 3Ghz (dual core)
   8GB RAM
   156GB of storage
Update: running ls -lh tells me that hd2,gpt1's label is Xubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64
Booting from my laptop worked fine. I don't know why it didn't work on my desktop.
What steps do I have to take in order to boot into the default installation?

Download xubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64 for full dvd version

for reference https://www.theregister.com/2024/04/30/xubuntu_2404_snapless_ubuntu/

After searching for ages, I found at least a clue to boot at this question:
Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8: UEFI vs Legacy mode
Thanks to it I know I can load kernel from casper/vmlinux
And initrd from casper/initrd
The operation went successfully and I got in the live environment
What I did:
set pager=1 #easier to read
ls -lh #see where the live environment was installed to
linux (hd[number],got[number])/casper/vmlinux #set kernel 
initrd (hd[number],got[number])/casper/initrd
boot

Hope this helped!

Nice. Can you please provide a real sample of what it might look when you have filled in those [number] -things?
